# git rebase results in control characters in file

Tags: git, rebase, meld

This just happened to me the second time:
I did a git rebase and had to merge the changes by hand. I used meld via `get mergetool` for this. It worked all well and I committed it and continued the rebase. After that I checked the diff and suddenly there where several control characters in the file and the diff looked strange. The broken places in the code weren't even at places affected by the merge.

```
    "just make a new list item
-    normal! gi^M[m
+    normal! gi
+[m
    call s:clone_marker_from_to(a:lnum, a:lnum+1)
```

Any idea what could be the cause for this and how to avoid it in the future?

Comment: But why would they end up in the file?

Comment: That should not happen. I'll assume you've checked and the files did not contain those characters before the merge. I'd say something is wrong with your mergetool. Try redoing the merge with a text editor. I'd also suggest checking if there's anything fishy in your git config with `git config -l`.